# MATLAB figures: Setting linewidth and font-size do not work as wish

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm plotting some simple figures and save them into TIFF images using `print` function. But in my saved images the lines are very thick and the texts are very big. So I have to set the `LineWidth` and `FontSize` to a very small value to make sure my figure looks good. For now I set `LineWidth` to `0.05`. And in my opinion for a 72dpi image it should be 0.05 pixels wide. But in my image it seems to be 1 pixel. However, if I set `LineWidth` to `1` I get the axes borders' width of about 10 pixels! (I suppose it should be 1pt * 1/72in/pt * 72px/inch = 1px). Am I doing wrong?

One thing to mention: My image is very high(324 inches) as I have 36 subplots in a column.

---

Following are my code. Notice that I set the border width of the axes to `1`.

```
function [  ] = draw_seq_1( raw_years, year_rng, raw_data, name, datarng )

year_span = year_rng(1):year_rng(end);
data = raw_data(:, find(raw_years==year_rng(1)):find(raw_years==year_rng(end)));

figure(1);
set(gcf, 'Visible', 'off');
base_pos = [0, 0, 18, 6 * size(data,1)];
set(gcf, 'PaperPositionMode', 'manual');
set(gcf, 'unit', 'inches');
set(gcf, 'position', base_pos);
set(gcf, 'paperunits', 'inches');
set(gcf, 'paperposition', base_pos);
for i = 1:size(data,1)
    data_to_plot = data(i,:);
    subplot(size(data,1),1,i);
    plot(year_span, data_to_plot, 'LineWidth', 0.1, 'Color', [0.4 0.6 0.7]);
    hold on;
    plot(year_span, 1+zeros(size(year_span)), 'LineWidth', 0.1, 'Color', [0 0 0]+0.5, 'LineStyle', '--');
    title(sprintf('%s(%d-%d) # %d', name, year_rng(1), year_rng(end), datarng(1)+i-1));
    set(gca, 'YLim', [0, max(0.1, max(data_to_plot)*1.05)] );
    set(gca, 'YTick', [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
    % here set the border width of the axes
    set(gca, 'LineWidth', 1);
    set(gca, 'FontSize', 1);
    set(gca, 'FontUnit', 'points');
end

print(gcf, sprintf('%s(%d-%d) # %d-%d.tiff', name, year_rng(1), year_rng(end), datarng(1), datarng(end)), '-dtiff', '-r72');

end
```

---

My saved images is below. You can see that the border width is very thick.[image]

Comment: Can't replicate your problem easily (see [mcve]), but have you tried explicitly setting the units (before you set the LineWidth, etc)?

Comment: Can't replicate. With random data, the code provided produces normal and expected plots. Have you modified the default properties of your axes?. Also if you try to plot few (2 or 3) plots intead of the 36, and set the visibility on, does the problem still appear?

Comment: I tried also to reproduce with random data, and nothing is wrong, the lines are thin as they should be. What Matlab version do you use?

Comment: Thanks to all. It seems that few plots works correctly. And I have explicitly set the units but it made no difference. Is something wrong with my MATLAB default preferences or something else?